# Any disadvantages of SELECT * in SQL?

Tags: sql, select

Let's say I have a program that executes SQL, and I want to query a table for the values in columns A, B and C (and let's suppose there are some columns I don't strictly need). What are the differences between SELECT * and SELECT A, B, C?

My thoughts so far below. Selecting only the columns you need:

- ...will require less memory to store the results.
- ...may make it a bit easier to parse the results in the program.
- ...will not be faster, unless the columns selected can all be retrieved with a covering index.

I feel there are probably further issues at play though.

Answer (score 7):

What you say is correct, but there is more.

Another very important issue with "select *" is what happens if the table schema changes.
If the client uses "select *" it will get a possibly unexpected set of columns (more columns, less columns, different order...). This is very bad.

If the client selects the exact column names (A, B, C) it wants, then it will get a result set with the expected format (if possible) or a specific, obvious error.

Also the issue of memory consumption and possibly network traffic for selecting unneded columns may be critical for "big" applications.

Answer (score 4):

Selecting with column name raises the probability that database engine can access the data from indexes rather than querying the table data....

A very relevant article you can read [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/07/18/the-real-reason-select-queries-are-bad-index-coverage.aspx)

`SELECT *` exposes your system to unexpected performance and functionality changes in the case when your database schema changes because you are going to get any new columns added to the table, even though, your code is not prepared to use or present that new data.

Answer (score 1):

there will be improvement in query processing if you use `select a,b,c from table`. For example, you are extracting records from a column which is the key column of non-clustered index; in such case, records will be retrieved from non-clustered index page, thus less number of physical database page reads issued. The less physical page read is always good sign for better performance.

**Point to Note for SQL Server**

1. SQL Sever by default copies all the columns to buffer pool, irrespective of column used in the SELECT query.
2. Though you don’t find much performance impact in the SQL Server query processing, it is good to use only the columns you needed as this will increase the overall system performance.

More : [SELECT * Vs. SELECT COLUMNS – SQL Server Optimization Techniques](http://www.discoversql.blogspot.ca/2012/04/select-vs-select-columns-sql-server.html)