# A sql query to fetch data of both table even if related id is not available

Tags: mysql, sql, fetch

I have to  table ledger and accounthead

accounthead

```
id | name   | phone
1  | Saijal | 989898    
2  | Shakya | 878787
```

ledger

```
id | accid | dr    | cr
1  |  1    | 10000 | 5000
```

Sql i tried

```
select * from ledger full join accounthead on accid = accounthead.id 
where accid=1
```

It gives all result i want but id accid=2 it shows null but i want all information from accounthead even if it has no data in ledger

Comment: If this was MySQL, your query would fail, which leaves me a little perplexed :-(

Answer (score 1):

[`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/left-join.php) is what you need which will return all rows from `ledger` table and only matching rows from `accounthead`

```
SELECT ledger.id AS ledger_id, ledger.accid, ledger.dr, ledger.cr,
accounthead.name, accounthead.phone
FROM accounthead LEFT JOIN ledger
ON accounthead.id = ledger.accid
```

Also, [do not use `SELECT *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753181/any-disadvantages-of-select-in-sql), rather use only the columns needed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would approach such problems using `LEFT JOIN`.  The first table contains all the rows you want in the result set.  The second has the "added" information.

```
select . . .  -- whatever columns you want
from accounthead ah left join
     ledger l
     on l.accid = ah.id ;
```

The columns from `ledger` for `ah.id`s that have no match in `l.accid` will be `NULL`.

You also have the condition `where l.accid = 1`.  I am guessing that this is not really needed, and the above does what you want.